# Cloud Composer vs Cloud Dataproc Workflow Template

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-composer

For running and orchestrating a few Spark jobs, some in parallel and some in a series.
What's the main difference between orchestration using Cloud Composer vs. a Dataproc workflow template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very similar. DAG in the 2 cases. The main differences are:

- Dataproc Workflow use YAML workflow definition, can run only Dataproc jobs, and no additional cost
- Composer use Python and operator, can run different type of jobs but require specific deployment (Composer Cluster) that incurs additional costs (about $400 per month for a small cluster)

Comment: Thanks. Yes I understand the differences in terms of cost and procedures. My question is more like "is there anything Cloud Composer can do while Dataproc cannot?" (and vice versa)

Comment: Cloud Composer can invoke another services and APIs. Dataproc workflow dans only orchestrate Dataproc jobs